# Backtracking and Meta Characters

Tags: regex

I was reading a book about regex. There was a basic example which I failed to understand.

let's say I search `/cat/`

and the word `camel` comes up.

The book says first it matches `c` (c matches),then it goes to `a` (a matches ) then when `m` comes up it fails. Then, it will backtrack to `a` to try matching the pattern again. I fail to understand why does it backtrack to `a` and what pattern is it looking for.

The second question is about matching a number

`/var[[(][0-9][\])] /`

I failed to understand what this line of regex means. (What it's trying to search)

Which character sets are being escaped?

Comment: The format of Stackoverflow is not really suited for multiple questions in the same Q&A. I tried answering both of your questions, but please refrain from asking multiple questions in the same post in the future. If you have multiple questions to ask, you are encouraged to ask multiple, separate questions on the site.

Comment: [Regex101 has a nice debugger where you can visualize your first question](https://regex101.com/r/ivx7N6/2/debugger) step by step. The red arrow on top shows when backtracking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try going on your match step by step.

First, it will match `ca` perfectly, since it is present on both the pattern and the string. Note that this match starts at `c`.

Then, it will try to continue matching with `cam`. This does not match the pattern, so it fails. Since it failed, the engine has to try matching again, from a new starting position. It already tried starting at `c`, so, for the next try, it will move the cursor one character to the right, which is `a`. Note that this is the `a` on `camel`, not the `a` on `/cat/`.

BTW, the pattern it is looking for is `cat`. That is, after all, what you want it to find, isn't it?

Your second pattern has several parts:

- `var` will match the string "var" literally.
- `[[(]` will match either a `[` or a `(`. Note that both of these don't need to be escaped, because they're inside a list match.
- `[0-9]` will match any digits (more pedantically, any character between `0` and `9`)
- `[\])]` will match either a `]` or a `)`. Note that the character `]` needs to be escaped, because otherwise it would mean the end of the list, which we don't want.

Knowing this, the answer is simple: It will search for `var` followed by a single digit between brackets or parenthesis. Any of these would match:

```
var(0)
var[5]
var(3]
var[9)
```

Note that the last two are probably not what the author intended. Try to think how could we guarantee that a match of `[` must always be followed by `]`, and the same for `(` and `)`.

Comment: i like your explanation on bactracking +1

Comment: What if i want to include backslash and at same time exclude ] is it okay? [\\])]